# SegNet - CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS (11 vs. 0) CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR

Tags: neural-network, caffe

Im trying to train my own dataset on SegNet (with caffe), I prepared the dataset same as [segnet tutorial](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/tutorial.html). when I try to run the train, it shows me this error:

```
I0915 08:33:50.851986 49060 net.cpp:482] Collecting Learning Rate and Weight Decay.
I0915 08:33:50.852017 49060 net.cpp:247] Network initialization done.
I0915 08:33:50.852030 49060 net.cpp:248] Memory required for data: 1064448016
I0915 08:33:50.852730 49060 solver.cpp:42] Solver scaffolding done.
I0915 08:33:50.853065 49060 solver.cpp:250] Solving VGG_ILSVRC_16_layer
I0915 08:33:50.853080 49060 solver.cpp:251] Learning Rate Policy: step
F0915 08:33:51.324506 49060 math_functions.cu:123] Check failed: status == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS (11 vs. 0)  CUBLAS_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fa27a0d3daa  (unknown)
    @     0x7fa27a0d3ce4  (unknown)
    @     0x7fa27a0d36e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7fa27a0d6687  (unknown)
    @     0x7fa27a56946e  caffe::caffe_gpu_asum<>()
    @     0x7fa27a54b264  caffe::SoftmaxWithLossLayer<>::Forward_gpu()
    @     0x7fa27a440b29  caffe::Net<>::ForwardFromTo()
    @     0x7fa27a440f57  caffe::Net<>::ForwardPrefilled()
    @     0x7fa27a436745  caffe::Solver<>::Step()
    @     0x7fa27a43707f  caffe::Solver<>::Solve()
    @           0x406676  train()
    @           0x404bb1  main
    @     0x7fa2795e5f45  (unknown)
    @           0x40515d  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
```

my dataset is `.jpg` (train) `.png` (labels gray-scale images) and `.txt` file as in the tutorial. what can be the problem? thanks for helping

Comment: when I change the:
`loss_param: {
    weight_by_label_freqs: true
    ignore_label: 2
    class_weighting: 99
    class_weighting: 1
  }` in the `loss layer` the problem change to: `math_functions.cu:123] Check failed: status == CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS (13 vs. 0)  CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED`

`

Comment: I solve it. the problem was that my GT images was with alpha layer. it was wrong. code line example: `img = Image.open(filename).convert('L')` (and not (LA))

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Could you give a proper answer? rather than answering your question in the comments?

Comment: @thigi your ground truth images must be 1 channel (without alpha channel). so I converted them from `RGB` to `L` images.

Comment: Ok :) and you store your images in a png which could have values from 0-255 but you only use values: 0,1,2  for example?

Comment: @thigi correct!

Comment: Ok how did you retrieve the output in python? I have something like this: [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549334/caffe-pixel-wise-classification-regression) maybe you could give me a little bit of help. I am trying this now for more than a week and I am frustrated and clueless. Any little help is apprreciated.

Comment: Because the output is a 3 channel output. How does this work, or rather how do you retrieve the output image of that 3 channel output since the 3 channels correspond to my 3 labels.

Comment: @thigi the number of colors in your GT images should be the same as your number of classes! [for example, if you have 3 classes, your GT images should be with 1 2 and 3 colors (0-255), and number of output= 3] ill check your question.

Comment: Yeah this is what I have. But my  1,2,3 colour in my case are 0,1,2 because I thought I cannot have colour 0, 122, and 233 for example. I will continue at my question after you have hopefully given me advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ground-truth images should be 1 channel `0-255` images without alpha layer, so the NN will recognise the difference between the classes.

```
img = Image.open(filename).convert('L') # Not 'LA' (A - alpha)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [isn4](https://github.com/isn4), Here is the resolution:
Turns out you have to change the range of the pixel values as well as the actual number of pixel values. Segnet gets confused if you have 256 possible pixel values (0-255) and don't have class weightings for each of them. So I changed all of my PNG label images from 255 and 0 as the pixel possibilities to 1 and 0 as the pixel possibilities.
Here's my python script for doing so:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('/usr/local/project/old_png_labels/label.png, 0)
a_img = np.array(img, np.double)
normalized = cv2.normalize(img, a_img, 1.0, 0.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
cv2.imwrite('/usr/local//project/png_labels/label.png, normalized)
```