# caffe pixel-wise classification / regression

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

What I want to do is to do a simple pixel-wise classification or regression task. Therefore I have an input image and a ground_truth. What I want to do is to do an easy segmentation task where I have a circle and a rectangle. And I want to train, where the circle or where the rectangle is. That means I have an ground_truth images which has value "1" at all the locations where the circle is and value "2" at all the locations where the rectangle is. Then I have my images and ground_truth images as input in form of .png images.

[image: circle] [image]

Then I think I can either to a regression or classification task depending on my loss layer: I have been using the fully convolutional AlexNet from [fcn alexnet](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn-alexnet/train.prototxt)

classification:

```
layer {
  name: "upscore"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "score_fr"
  top: "upscore"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 3 ## <<---- 0 = backgrund 1 = circle 2 = rectangle
    bias_term: false
    kernel_size: 63
    stride: 32
  }
}
layer {
  name: "score"
  type: "Crop"
  bottom: "upscore"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "score"
  crop_param {
    axis: 2
    offset: 18
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss" ## <<----
  bottom: "score"
  bottom: "ground_truth"
  top: "loss"
  loss_param {
    ignore_label: 0
  }
}
```

regression:

```
layer {
  name: "upscore"
  type: "Deconvolution"
  bottom: "score_fr"
  top: "upscore"
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 1 ## <<---- 1 x height x width 
    bias_term: false
    kernel_size: 63
    stride: 32
  }
}
layer {
  name: "score"
  type: "Crop"
  bottom: "upscore"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "score"
  crop_param {
    axis: 2
    offset: 18
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss" ## <<----
  bottom: "score"
  bottom: "ground_truth"
  top: "loss"
}
```

However, this produces not even the results I want to have. I think there is something wrong with my understanding of pixel-wise classification / regression. Could you tell me where my mistake is?

**EDIT 1**

For regression the retrieval of the output would look like this:

```
output_blob = pred['result'].data

predicated_image_array = np.array(output_blob)
predicated_image_array = predicated_image_array.squeeze()
print predicated_image_array.shape
#print predicated_image_array.shape

#print mean_array
range_value = np.ptp(predicated_image_array)
min_value = predicated_image_array.min()
max_value = predicated_image_array.max()

# make positive
predicated_image_array[:] -= min_value

if not range_value == 0:
    predicated_image_array /= range_value

predicated_image_array *= 255
predicated_image_array = predicated_image_array.astype(np.int64)
print predicated_image_array.shape

cv2.imwrite('predicted_output.jpg', predicated_image_array)
```

This is easy since the output is 1 x height x width and the values are the actual output values. But how would one retrieve the output for classification / SotMaxLayer since the output is 3 (num labels) x height x width. But I do not know the meaning of the content of this shape.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, your problem is not `regression`, but `classification`!

if you want to teach the net recognise circles and rectangles you have to make a different data set - an images and labels, for example: `circle - 0 and rectangle - 1`. you do it by making text file that containsthe images path and the images labels, for example: `/path/circle1.png 0 /path/circle2.png 0 /path/rectangle1.png 1 /path/rectangle1.png 1`. here is a nice [tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/training-and-deploying-deep-learning-networks-with-caffe-optimized-for-intel-architecture) for a problem like yours. good luck.

Comment: No no! I want to do a pixel-wise classification or regression task.  Just an easy one. I know that you can do that with a normal  classification task but I want to do pixel-wise classification. My thoughts were to have a segmentation / classification. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: You could also think of: I have circles and rectangle in one image and I want to do segmentation! I just want to be able to do a really easy pixel-wise prediction task, since I know how to do the standard classification but I want to work wit pixel-wise predictions later and do more difficult tasks!

Comment: so you can do it by `segmentation`. for each image (circle/rectangle) you have to make a GT image (0-255). number of classes in each image is 2 (background and geometric shape), so `num_output: 2`. set the background as 0 and the shape 1. good luck.

Comment: Ok, but I thought I would set 0 for backgrund 1 for circle and 2 for rectangle? GT image will only have values 0,1,2 then rather than 0,1,...255 right? 
And how do you retrieve the output image, since you retrieve a 3 x height x width image ?

Comment: if you want both shapes be in the same image you'll have 3 classes -> `num_output: 2`. here is a [tutorial][1] for an segmentation problem like yours. 


  [1]: http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/

Comment: sorry `num_output: 3`

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this tutorial. But I am not using their stuff. THe only thing I do not know is how do I get my output image? I am using the python API. I will add my "testing" code to my question. Could you "correct" your question?

Comment: I think the code would look something like this [link](https://github.com/alexgkendall/SegNet-Tutorial/blob/master/Scripts/test_segmentation_camvid.py) but I am not sure how to alter it for my case